# Another way of saying 'points to remember'?

Tags: word-choice

I need help in putting this statement into a more structured heading:

> Points to remember

Is there another way of saying this?

Comment: Key points works, too.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Why, User, please? *Points to remember* doesn't seem in need of improvement unless the context is very unusual.